# Generate alternating pattern with each row increasing the amount of said value

Tags: python

I want to generate the following pattern where each new row would have increasing amounts of alternating values between +1 and -1. I.e Row 1 will have +1 -1 ..., Row 2 will have +1 + 1 - 1 - 1 ...

```
+1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1
+1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1
+1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
```

The following code does the same but misses out on a key aspect which is: Each new row will have more no. of alternating -1's. How can I capture this constraint with the following logic?

```py
def generate_matrix_pattern(n):
    matrix = [[1] * n for _ in range(n)]
    pos = 1
    neg = -1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            if (j-i) % 2 == 0:
                matrix[i][j] = pos
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = neg
    
    return matrix
```

Gives the pattern:

```
+1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1
+1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Also, I recommend describing, in words, the pattern you are trying to create. At first glance it wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to clearly understand and describe the pattern precisely. My way of describing it is like this:

> For the `ith` row in the matrix, alternate `+1` `i` times and `-1` `i` times.

A trick of integer division can give you the correct results. Change `if (j-i) % 2 == 0:` to `if (j // i) % 2 == 0:`.

Comment: Gives a zero divison error hmm

Comment: @aquaticdigest Good point. This can be easily fixed by an appropriate addition. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: if i != 0 and (j // i) % 2 == 0: something like this works but the first row is actually misconfigured

Comment: Uh.  Try something else.  The first row has alternates of 1, but i = 0.  The second row has alternatives of 2, but i = 1.  The third row has alternates of 3, but i = 2.  What does that suggest. . . .

Comment: Looks good! if (j // (i+1)) % 2 == 0: works the magic

Answer (score 1):

This is in addition to what @code-apprentice wrote above.

Now that you know that know the matching function `f(i, j)` that returns True if you're supposed to return +1 and False if you're supposed to return -1.  So `2 * f(i, j) - 1` returns exactly the value you want to put into each element of the array.

```
def generator(i, j): 
    return 2 * (j // (i + 1) % 2 == 0) - 1

matrix = np.fromfunction(generator, (10, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

```
from pprint import pprint
def generate_matrix_pattern(n):
    pos = 1
    neg = -1
    matrix = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        row = ([pos]*i + [neg]*i)*(n//i)
        matrix.append(row[:n])
    
    return matrix

pprint(generate_matrix_pattern(10))
```

Output:

```
[[1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1],
 [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Yes, I misread the pattern the first time.

Comment: This does not generate the desired output as shown in the OP. The first row alternates + and -. The second row alternates pairs. The third row alternates triplets, etc.